# openldap cacerts directory symbolic link to /etc/pki/tls/certs - Yes/No? Why?

Tags: linux, centos, ssl-certificate, openldap, tls

Every single article/how-to/blog on openldap talks about putting the ldap cert for ldaps in the /etc/openldap/cacerts directory.

I am wondering why not just put the cert(s) in /etc/pki/tls/certs and make a symbolic link between /etc/openldap/cacerts -> /etc/pki/tls/certs? That way all certs are in one place on the system and not spread out in various directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specific to openldap, this is generally done for security reasons:

- the software package in question may do a [`chroot`](http://mdoc.su/o/chroot.2) into its own directory within `/etc`, and would then be unable to follow any symbolic links outside of the changed root
- the software may be programmed in such a way as to specifically prohibit it from following any kind of symbolic links in the first place

It's all done in order to ensure that any kind of exploit would be limited and isolated to one piece of software, and the adversary would have a harder time accessing arbitrary files on the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter where you put regular certificates, CA certificates and private keys, as long as the application in question, and the crypto library it uses, can read and understand the files. Various limitations might be in place depending on whether your application (OpenLDAP/slapd in your case) is linked against OpenSSL or GnuTLS. There also might be artificial limitations in the application itself or imposed by security frameworks like AppArmor or SELinux.

For example on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (server) the libvirt daemon, which looks for its CA certificates in `/etc/pki/CA/cacerts.pem`, doesn't seem to tolerate when that file is larger than a few kilobytes. So it is not possible to just feed it the system-wide list of trusted CA certificates found in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` (on CentOS the equivalent is `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`, as you mentioned). I think this is a limitation of GnuTLS (one of many).

As I said: it depends on the application in question, the crypto library used and possible security frameworks in place. You can only try and see what works and what doesn't.